# And and remove classes when click on nav item and outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nav

I'm trying to build a tricky navigation menu that needs to do the following:

When click in a nav item, **.active** class should be added to that item and removed from the previous one.

When one dropdown is open and you click to open another one the previous one should close and the new one should open in one click.

When click in a nav item it should open its respective dropdown container (at the moment it opens every dropdowns at once.) 
and it should add **.black-bg** class to **main-container** underneath it.

When click anywhere outside the dropdown its active class **.active** should be removed as well as the class **.black-bg** in **main-container** underneath it.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".showup").slideToggle(200);
    $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
});
$(".showup").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $(".showup").slideUp(50);
});
```

This is what I came up with so far:

**SEE DEMO**

[See demo here](https://codepen.io/TiagoDeSousa/pen/MGmdKg)

I hope the above makes sense and someone could help me as I'm really stuck with this nav.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not using jQuery for this because of the exact issues you're running into. Try using [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) or [Preact](https://github.com/developit/preact)

However, if you insist on using jQuery, your click function should select the item that has "active", and modify it and its siblings accordingly.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGwdXO

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      return;
    }
      $(".active").parent().find(".showup").slideToggle(200);
      $(".active").toggleClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).parent().find(".showup").slideToggle(200);
      if (!$(".main-container").hasClass("black-bg")) {
        $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
      }
  });
  $(".showup").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
  });

});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $(".active").parent().find(".showup").slideUp(50);
    $(".active").toggleClass("active");
    if ($(".main-container").hasClass("black-bg")) {
      $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
    }
});
```

Comment: I really have to use jQuery. Your example is quite good thank you. However Item 3 and Item 4 seem to have some issues on click.

Comment: @Tiago If you mean they have no dropdown, it's how you defined your HTML--there's no problem, it's expected behavior. Examine your code very carefully. Item 3 and Item 4 have no 
"nav-content" in them.

Comment: One weird thing is after make it live http://nqubo.com/nav/ it behaves really badly

Comment: Your website is using the old code: http://nqubo.com/nav/scripts.js

Please mark my answer as correct and open a new issue if you're having server problems

Comment: You're right. I must be too tired lol. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just noticed one more thing. When you click in the active item it should close everything as well.

Comment: @Tiago I recommend trying some stuff to make it work or hiring a developer! :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Just add class showup1, showup2, etc and data-showup="1", data-showup="2" attr in each menu item. (Working in nav items 1 and 2).

```
$(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    var showup = $(this).data('showup');
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".showup").hide();
    $(".showup"+showup).slideToggle(200);
    $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
});
```

[Run](https://codepen.io/gersart/pen/ZoyWeG)